# How to load a foodmart database in to postgres

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

i have installed a PostgreSQL database.Now i need to download and import a food mart database to practice some reporting techniques.I am new to this field so do not know where to start.Please it will be very helpful if anyone can provide me a guidance to start it.

Comment: Sounds like this is something you need to ask your course instructor/tutor/etc. You have not provided even close to enough information for anyone here to help you. For a start, what "food mart database"?

Comment: @Craig Ringer. i heard that food mart database is a sample database to practice data analysis techniques .i am looking for that sample database .tar file to import it into a PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

This repo contains the foodmart data loader for Postgres, Mysql, Sqlserver, Sybase

https://github.com/OSBI/foodmart-data

All you need to do is clone it and launch the following script:

`sh FoodMartLoader.sh --db postgres`

connection props are set inside the script

For Clickhouse DB2 and SAP Hana and some other DBs look at the **branches** of this
fork:
https://github.com/contiamo/foodmart-data-public